# unselect Radio Button and Disable Submit when all inputs are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have an interactive map which connects over PHP to an database.
Since i'm pretty new to javascript i have some question.

We have around 15 text input and one dropdown input.
I only provide the Problematic parts of our code.

**HTML**

```
     <div class="nav nav-sidebar">
       <form action="./action_page.php" method="post">
        <ul class="dropdown-item" id="u3">
          <div data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class ="btn btn-default" style="float:left;">
              <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" name="politic" id="politic" value="2"> Trump
            </label>
            <label class ="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-right: 20%; float:right;">
              <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" name="politic" id="politic" value="1"> Hillary
            </label>
          </div>
        </ul>
        <button input type="submit" id="submit-button" class="submit-button" value="Submit">Submit</button>
       </form>
       <button type="button" onclick="test()" class="clear-button">Reset</button>
     </div>
```

**JS**

```
function test(){

  $('input[name="politic"]').prop('checked', false);

}
```

1. How can I disable the Submit button if atleast 1 input is emtpy?
2. My test() function resets the value of `"poltics"` but the Button is still selected. How can I fix this?

I would appreciate to not get the working code, more like a guideline how to start on this Problem, or if you want to provide code, I would appreciate some shorts explanation.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `disabled` property of the button to true?

Comment: did you get the chance to test my answer @sHamann?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added example with 3 input fields that will be empty till all of them are filled.. also for radios I have added class removal that was missing,,

hope that helps, cheers

EDIT: try now..
EDIT2: try now :)

```js
function checkallinputs(){
  var ch = false;
  $('form input[type="text"]').each(function(el){
    if( $(this).val() != '' ) ch = true; return false;
  });
  if( ch ){ $('button[type="submit"]').removeClass('disabled'); return true; }
  if(!ch ){ $('button[type="submit"]').addClass('disabled'); return false; }
}

// run this on document.ready or in (function())() self exe block on page
checkallinputs();

$('form input[type="text"]').on( 'change', function(){ checkallinputs(); });
// disable submit
$( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function(){ return checkallinputs(); });
// reset radio ==>remove class
function test(){
  $('input[name="politic"]').prop('checked', false);
  $('input[name="politic"]').parent().removeClass('active');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


       <form action="./action_page.php" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input1">Input 1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input2">Input 2</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input3">Input 3</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input3">
  </div>

<div class="checkbox">
         <div data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class ="btn btn-default" style="float:left1;">
              <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" name="politic" id="politic1" value="2"> Trump
            </label>
            <label class ="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-right: 20%; float:right;">
              <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" name="politic" id="politic2" value="1"> Hillary
            </label>
          </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default disabled">Submit</button>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="test()" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>

</form>
```

Comment: form getting submitted even if submit is disabled ^^

Comment: try now..now I added to return 0|1 and hook that to submit event,, so even ENTER key on fields would be blocked if not all fields are filled by user

Comment: Hey, i tested the remove focus from the radio and it worked perfectly.
For The first part of my question i run into Problems. I understand your code, but it wont work on my code. Also i dont want  evrything to be filled with input, only one is enough to send send the form on submit. And your function doesnt work even if my whole Form is filled. My Form has `7 <input type=text>` `1 <selectt>` `1 <input type=radio>`

Comment: It works on id="input1", but not for the Other ones. Also The Radio Button wont change the Submit-button to enable.

Comment: So, i got it to work on my code with your Code and some tweaks. If you fix your Code above I will set you to the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I disable the Submit button if atleast 1 input is emtpy?

There are a few ways you can get this done.

**Number One:**

The easiest way is to add in the required attribute to the field, and the user would not be able to submit the form unless all required field are filled up. This is not the recommended way though as it depends on the browser and I believe there are work arounds for this.

```
<input type="text" name="username" required>
```

**Number Two:**

Another way is to add an onkeyup event handler to all your inputs, which calls a function where you check if all the inputs are filled up. Here, by default, you have your submit button disabled, and when all the inputs are filled, you can enable your submit button. This is not the best way since the user might not know why the button is disabled unless you specifically give a feedback, like making the borders red for invalid fields. Also running the validation after every keyup might be demanding for the application.

**Number Three:**

The one which I would prefer and recommend is this. You can leave the submit button enabled, and bind it to a click event where you check whether your validation is satisfied, that is, for your case you check if any input is empty and if one is empty, then you don't submit the form and display an alert or give the user a feedback to fill in the field. You might want to set focus to an empty field too.

> My test() function resets the value of "poltics" but the Button is
>   still selected. How can I fix this?

What did you mean by "the button is still selected"? The Reset button? You can set focus to another input of your choice if you want

```
$(.'input-name').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How can I disable the Submit button if atleast 1 input is emtpy?

You just need to keep trace of the change events of the inputs, like the following. If an input is checked, then you have to re-enable the submit button. If the reset button is used, you need to disable the submit button. This button can be disabled by default.

> 2. My test() function resets the value of "poltics" but the Button is still selected. How can I fix this?

As you provided your code, the radio buttons for both politicians successfully deselected.

```js
function test(){

  $('input[name="politic"]').prop('checked', false);
  $('#submit-button').prop('disabled', true);
}

$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function () {
  // Here we set the button to not disabled if the radio was selected
    $('#submit-button').prop('disabled', !$(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav nav-sidebar">
       <form action="./action_page.php" method="post">
        <ul class="dropdown-item" id="u3">
          <div data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class ="btn btn-default" style="float:left;">
              <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" name="politic" id="politic" value="2"> Trump
            </label>
            <label class ="btn btn-default" style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-right: 20%; float:right;">
              <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" name="politic" id="politic" value="1"> Hillary
            </label>
          </div>
        </ul>
        <button type="submit" id="submit-button" class="submit-button" value="Submit" disabled>Submit</button>
       </form>
       <button type="button" onclick="test()" class="clear-button">Reset</button>
     </div>
```